# Xamarin cross platform - Couldn't connect debugger

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mono

After installing everything it couldn't create emulator. Running emulator from android studio. Using a Hello world Xamarin app. It installs on the emulator successfully but stops after showing a white screen. Then closes automatically showing this error:

> Couldn't connect debugger. You can see more details in Xamarin Diagnostic output and the full exception on logs.

Manually opening the app also fails to show second time but opeing it third time shows the UI that has only a label and a button.
Third time it works. Also closed android studio so that theres no conflict on debugger.

Now what is wrong here?

Comment: it has given you a very explicit hint - "You can see more details in Xamarin Diagnostic output and the full exception on logs."  Have you bothered to try this?

Comment: need details about how to do that. Couldn't find.

Comment: Those bottom two tabs "Error List" & "Output" has no message except that one. Wheres Diagnostic output & log and what will happen with those?

Comment: what does android studio have to do with Xamarin?

Comment: run emulator from it.

Comment: What is the version of your IDE ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017. (pro). All downloaded/added recently.

Comment: chances are, you're hitting a very old bug, upgrade to VS2019

Comment: Okay. I will give VS2019 a try.

Comment: I'am having the same problem on the newest VS2019 available

Answer (score 7):

Clean and Rebuild the Solution Is working fine for me, also in some cases you need to uninstall the app from Device.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a smarter solution? Rebuilding solution takes some time and this issue happens to me quite frequently so I end up losing bunch of time to this misbehavior.

Comment: @TipsyFingers welcome to Microsoft software. :(

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem after updating Android Sdk from Android Studio, then Visual Studio showed that error. A restart will help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should mainly because of the device connectivity, so I change the cable and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a factory reset on my emulator device via Android Device Manager fixed this for me.